# ajaxed data can't be picked up by jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

On document load I run the following ajax script.

```
function LoadData() {             
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "display.php",             
    dataType: "html",                
    success: function(text){                    
        $("#responsecontainer").html(text); 
    }

});
}
```

Here is the PHP script it pulls the data from.
**Yes I know it's depreciated and most likely vunerable to attack.**

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
$counter = 0;
echo '<table  class="table" id="tableShow">
<tr>
<td align=center><b>ID</b></td>
<td align=center><b>Name</b></td>
<td align=center><b>Quantity</b></td>
<td align=center><b>Price</b></td></td>
<td align=center><b>Description</b></td>
<td align=center><b>Edit Item</b></td>
';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from user ORDER BY `id` ASC");

while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{   
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align=center>$data[0]</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>$data[1]</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>$data[3]</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>$data[4]</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>$data[2]</td>";
    echo '<td align=center><a class="btn Edititem btn-info btn-small" id="'.++$counter.'">Test1</a></td>';
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

As you can see, within the table it has a button for each row.
`<a class="btn Edititem btn-info btn-small" id="'.++$counter.'">Test1</a></td>`

I then have this script.

```
  $(".Edititem").click(function () 
    {
    $('#Edit').modal('show');
      $("#updateResults").click(function (){
        $.ajax({                                      
          url: 'api.php',        
          data: "id="+ $(this).find('a').attr('id'),
          dataType: 'json',    
          success: function(data)
          { var id = data[0]; 
            var name = data[1];
            var desc = data[2];
            var quant = data[3];
            var price = data[4];
            $('#inner-title').html(name);
            $('#itemid').val(id);
            $('#Name').val(name);
            $('#quant').val(quant);
            $('#price').val(price);
            $('#desc').val(desc);
            $('#Edit').modal('hide');
            $('#success').alert();
          },
          error: function(){$("#failure").alert();}       
        }); 
      });
  });
```

It seems that the html thats pulled from the PHP script, is invisible to jQuery. For example, when you click on one of the buttons, it should launch the modal I have within my page, however, it don't happen and I get no console errors either. But if I just insert the button into the `#responsecontainer` like so:

```
<div id="responsecontainer">
  <a class="btn Edititem btn-info btn-small" id="'.++$counter.'">Test1</a>
</div>
```

jQuery can find it, and the modal launches?

What is wrong here?

Comment: *"I then have this script."* that script is likely executing before the elements it affects exist.

Comment: To paraphrase @KevinB: the script is executing when the page first loads. Then you add some links. Javascript has not attached the event handler to those links because they didn't exist when the script was run. You'll need to add some code to your `success` event handler to add the event handler to the new links.

Comment: @Kryten So I'm wrong in thinking the order would be `get data from php -> display on the page -> run javascript`  for it to work?

Comment: @AshleyBrown That's not what you are doing. You are doing something like: `load basic html -> register click function & launch ajax request -> add data from ajax request`. At the moment you register your click function, the data is not there. Apart from that an ID cannot start with a number (or be only a number) so you might run into browser inconsistencies with that. You could easily use a data attribute.

Comment: @jeroen I understand, but thats not the case. The order is
`load html -> launch ajax request -> (modal html) -> click function underneath modal html`

Comment: @AshleyBrown Based on the problem you have, that does not seem to be the case. Where does your click function reside?

Comment: @jeroen See the following Pastie - http://pastie.org/9004838#14-15

Comment: precisely, the click event binding gets executed before the dom is ready, before the ajax request completes.

Comment: @AshleyBrown You seem to misunderstand ansynchronous ajax requests and `$(document).ready()`. `$(document).ready()` gets executed when the DOM has finished loading, so up until the last line of html **and your click handler** and all included scripts. Then the ajax request fires, takes some more time and - long after `$(document).ready()` - your table gets added.

Comment: OH... yeah, failed to realize I wrapped it in the `.ready()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use `.on()` jQuery function.

[.on() | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Consider following script update:

```
$("#responsecontainer").on("click", ".Edititem", function() {
    $('#Edit').modal('show');
    $("#updateResults").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'api.php',
            data: "id=" + $(this).find('a').attr('id'),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data)
            {
                var id = data[0];
                var name = data[1];
                var desc = data[2];
                var quant = data[3];
                var price = data[4];
                $('#inner-title').html(name);
                $('#itemid').val(id);
                $('#Name').val(name);
                $('#quant').val(quant);
                $('#price').val(price);
                $('#desc').val(desc);
                $('#Edit').modal('hide');
                $('#success').alert();
            },
            error: function() {
                $("#failure").alert();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because when the document is loaded the elements are not loaded yet.

You can try the following. This does late binding on Jquery. Read More here https://api.jquery.com/on/

```
  $(document).on('click', '.Edititem', function (e) 
    {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#Edit').modal('show');
      $("#updateResults").click(function (){
        $.ajax({                                      
          url: 'api.php',        
          data: "id="+ $(this).find('a').attr('id'),
          dataType: 'json',    
          success: function(data)
          { var id = data[0]; 
            var name = data[1];
            var desc = data[2];
            var quant = data[3];
            var price = data[4];
            $('#inner-title').html(name);
            $('#itemid').val(id);
            $('#Name').val(name);
            $('#quant').val(quant);
            $('#price').val(price);
            $('#desc').val(desc);
            $('#Edit').modal('hide');
            $('#success').alert();
          },
          error: function(){$("#failure").alert();}       
        }); 
      });
  });
```